# GitHub: Grouping projects under single repo and private .git folders

Tags: git, github, gitlab, repository

I keep my assignment projects in a private repo called assignment. However, the `.git` is only under this repo and I removed the `.git` folders from each of the projects under this repo.

But in this situation, when I just want to keep a project under this repo, this project does not have its own git folder. But I want to make all the projects have its private repo while keeping them under assignment repo.

So, how can I make such structure? I just want to rely on specific git folders for each project instead of under assignment. But I think assignment must have git folder as it is repo and I will push my assignments into it. Any idea?

Comment: I'm far from sure that I understood your description but if it's multiple Git repositories referenced within another single Git repository, then you are looking for [Git Submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

Comment: Is there a better explanation instead of ugly Git Documentation page? I never found any useful info in it. On the other hand, my problem is clear. I just want to keep multiple projects with their git history separately (each project would have `.git` folder inside it) in a single repository.

Comment: I would recommend making your life simpler and not trying to have a parent git repo above all your assignments. If you want each assignment to have its own repo, then just have one repo per assignment, and keep your sandboxes structured together on your computer. Yes, you could use submodules, but that's just going to make your life more complicated for not real benefit.

Comment: But then my next question is, *why* does each assignment have to have its own git folder? You could just as easily have multiple assignments, each in its own folder, inside a single Git repo. Or is there a requirement from your professor that each assignment needs its own repo?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The first reason of trying to use single repository is just keeping each assignment in a single place on GitHub. Let's say the repo name `assignment` and project names `employee`, `car-parking`. Then only `asg` has its `.git` folder and the assignments in it not. Of course with this, I can also keep the history of each assignment. **But**, when I want to keep the `employee` separately, then I won't have its git history. That's why I want to keep each assignment in a single repo and why I have to keep them separately.

Comment: So, in this situation, is the best way for me keeping each assignment in a separate repository by adding a prefix to their names e.g. `asg-employee`, `asg-car-parking` and reach all of them on Github easily by sorting by name? Of course I can also add them to a group, but not effective. What would you suggest?